# How to know if a python programming is running under a profiler?

Tags: python, cprofile

Is there any methods that can be used to judge whether a Python script is currently running under profiler?

I have a program with GUI. I want to skip the GUI part when running under profiler so that the result is more accurate.

Comment: That depends on a profiler you use. You can always detect if your profiling modules are loaded, assuming you wouldn't be loading them when normally running your code.

Comment: You could also examine the execution stack  to detect if a function such as `cProfile.run` is being executed. If this is your program, you could perhaps simply add a `--no-gui` command line option and invoke that option when you run the profiler.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Explicit is better than implicit.](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0020/)  Just add a command line option to your program which disables the GUI.  If you're using `argparse`:

```
args.add_argument('--no-gui', action='store_true')
```